# Checkbox is not checked in DevExpress GridControl using wpf

Tags: wpf, checkbox, devexpress, gridcontrol

I am trying to work on DevExpress GridControl Checkbox column but problem is that when I binding the checkbox value in XAML code dynamically its not work perfectlly 
below I provide you my demo project code :-

XAML Code:-

```
<dxg:GridControl AutoPopulateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="0,40,0,0" Name="gridControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="318" Width="503">
            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView Name="tableView1" ShowTotalSummary="True" />
            </dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=EvenOdd}" Header="Even/Odd" />
                <dxg:GridColumn Name="PickColumn" Header="Pick" Width="30" 
                                    AllowColumnFiltering="False" AllowSorting="False">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsValid}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                            </CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn>
            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        </dxg:GridControl>
```

my cs file code:-

```
public class ss
{
  public bool IsValid { get; set; }
  public string EvenOdd { get; set; }
}
```

Code Behind:

```
    public List<ss> sList = new List<ss>();


    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                sList.Add(new ss { IsValid = true, EvenOdd = "Even" });
            }
            else
            {
                sList.Add(new ss { IsValid = false, EvenOdd = "Odd" });
            }
        }

       gridControl1.ItemsSource = sList;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding on to HighCore's answer. If you would like to edit the data in your grid.

See [ColumnBase.CellTemplate Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridColumnBase_CellTemplatetopic):

> - To enable data editing, use an editor shipped with the DevExpress Data Editors Library for WPF. The editor's Name must be set to
>     'PART_Editor'.
> - Standard controls can be used in CellTemplate only for display purposes. Data editing is not allowed.

Then,

```
xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors" 

<dxg:GridColumn Name="PickColumn" 
                Header="Pick" 
                Width="30" 
                AllowColumnFiltering="False" 
                AllowSorting="False">
    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <dxe:CheckEdit x:Name="PART_Editor"
                           EditValue="{Binding Path=Data.IsValid, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

You still need to use HighCore's implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Thnx @Willem and @ HighCore !

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to correct the binding inside the `CellTemplate`:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.IsValid}"/>
```

Second, your data items should implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx):

```
 public class ss:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isValid;
        private string _evenOdd;

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get { return _isValid; }
            set
            {
                _isValid = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsValid");
            }
        }

        public string EvenOdd
        {
            get { return _evenOdd; }
            set
            {
                _evenOdd = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EvenOdd");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   xmlns:dxgcore="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"


     <dxgcore:GridColumn Width="20"  
                         AllowEditing="True"  
                         Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                         Header="R"  
                         Visible="{Binding CheckboxSelection}"  
                         VisibleIndex="6">  
                 <dxgcore:GridColumn.CellTemplate>  
                   <DataTemplate>  
                     <dxe:CheckEdit HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                             Command="{Binding 
Path=View.DataContext.IsCheckedCommand}"  
                             CommandParameter="{Binding RowData.Row}"  
                             IsChecked="{Binding RowData.Row.IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                             IsEnabled="{Binding Path=View.DataContext.IsCheckBoxEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />  
                   </DataTemplate>  
                 </dxgcore:GridColumn.CellTemplate>  
               </dxgcore:GridColumn>
```

And Notifychanged property

```
private bool _isChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return _isChecked; }
    set
    {
        _isChecked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked");
    }
}
```